# How to display existing files on server in ngx-dropzone-wrapper on Angular 7

Tags: typescript, angular7, dropzone.js

I work on angular 7 project and i use ngx-dropzone-wrapper module for upload image to server web api
i can upload image with out problem
but i will show exist uploaded image in update mode .

My Html Side Code

```html
<dropzone class="dropzone-container" [config]="config" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start strech"
            #nationalDropZone (success)="onUploadSuccess($event)" fxFlex="auto" (init)="nationalDropZoneInit($event)"
            [message]="'Please Add '"></dropzone>
```

```
  @ViewChild('nationalDropZone') componentRef?: DropzoneComponent;
  dropzone: any;
```

And Here Initialize dropzone

```
  nationalDropZoneInit(arg: any): void {
  this.dropzone = this.componentRef.directiveRef.dropzone();
  }
```

Here I Read User information include user profile image in string url template
my return model from server have profileImageUrl property  which when enter on browser url can see image.
now i will add exist image with preview thumbnail on dropzone

```
this.accountService.getResellerProfile().subscribe((res: ResellerInfoModel) => {
//Add res.profileImageUrl  to dropzone
//I do not know how
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps.

```js
const dropzone = this.componentRef.directiveRef.dropzone();

const mockFile = { name: "some name", size: "some size" };

dropzone.emit( "addedfile", mockFile );
dropzone.emit( "thumbnail", mockFile, res.profileImageUrl );
dropzone.emit( "complete", mockFile);
```

I got some help from [this answer](https://github.com/zefoy/ngx-dropzone-wrapper/issues/114#issuecomment-405760051).